# Process Add a Dimension using AMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssas, cube

I am trying to Process a Large Dimension using '**ProcessADD**' and I was able to do it manually using a XMLA script ( with out-of-line bindings ). But the problem is, our application is flexible and users may add new levels to the dimension which means

- Manual intervention is required to prepare an XMLA script for the processADD everytime a new level is added. OR
- I should get the latest DSV definition for the dimension from the huge database XMLA using string manipulation and do some crazy find&replace stuff to get that to work.

Can we do the ProcessADD using AMO ?? If not, Can someone suggest me a better way to automate the ProcessADD even when the levels change .

*-- Since the question is about the approach not the code, I did not include any specific details about the structure of the relational table under the dimension or the structure of the dimension itself. Let me know if you need that information.*

Answer (score 0):

Working C# snippet for processing dimension through AMO :

```
svr.Connect([olapServerName]);
Database db = svr.Databases.FindByName([olapDatabaseName]);
Dimension dim = db.Dimensions.FindByName([dimname]);
dim.Process(ProcessType.ProcessData);
```

Please check if dim.Process(ProcessType.ProcessAdd) is available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Prabhash. I got the process Update, Process Data working on Dimensions . But I am having trouble using the processType.ProcessAdd. I get the error - ' does not match the structure of the metadata class hierarchy. '